# Bathroom sink and toilet shared drain

Tags: toilet, drain

I don’t know how to explain it other than referring to the drawing. Due to short distance between the toilet flange and the nearest drain pipe, and limited access from the sink, I couldn’t come up with better ideas. Would this pass the inspection?

[image: Drawing]

Comment: so the 1-1/2" is wet vent for the WC and drain for the sink? vent entering the WC drain from the underside looks fishy to me. or are those wyes laying mostly flat?

Comment: I do not think it will pass inspection especially with the smaller diameter pipes. Check with your local plumbing inspector, he is the one that has the final say!

Comment: @Jasen: the 1 1/5 vent is entering from the underside, but I can turn it and make it enter from a side. Do you think the rest is OK?

Comment: Get a copy of the plumbing code,  I suspect Gil is right that the wet vent is too slender.  if the WC is an addition then the 3" may need to be upgraded also.

Comment: 1 1/2" wet vent can support 1 DFU drain. I am mostly concerned with what's between the toilet and the main 3" pipe. And I tried to figure out our from the code - it's not simple :)